# Are there any Ruby gems for getting web host details like os , server

Tags: ruby, dns, rubygems, server-side, host

Are there any Ruby gems for getting web host details like os , server , dns servers & server side tech etc.,

Answer (score 0):

`HTTParty` can show you the response headers which should contain information like that, if it is made publicly available.

```
require 'httparty'
HTTParty.get('http://www.google.com').headers                                                 
#=> {
#  "date"=>["Wed, 13 Nov 2013 14:30:22 GMT"],
#  "expires"=>["-1"],
#  "cache-control"=>["private, max-age=0"],
#  "content-type"=>["text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"],
#  "set-cookie"=>["PREF=ID=e77b1a34a6c800b7:U=d34bac1ee0ebd206:FF=0:TM=1384353022:LM=1384353022:S=vJvIFTH7In_YgQ6s; expires=Fri, 13-Nov-2015 14:30:22 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.co.uk"],
#  "server"=>["gws"],
#  "x-xss-protection"=>["1; mode=block"],
#  "x-frame-options"=>["SAMEORIGIN"],
#  "connection"=>["close"]
#}

HTTParty.get('http://www.google.com').headers['server']                                              
#=> "gws"
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron ,hope this helps but any idea about server side stuff like php , ruby & dns servers etc., and even host operating system :)

Comment: Some webservers serve these details by default and they would appear in the headers. However, most people are smart enough to disable this since it can present vulnerabilities to a potential attacker. If it isn't served, you can't retrieve it easily.

Comment: so any idea about getting dns servers?